# Question about polypropylene with glass fiber reinforcement

Tags: filament-production

My 3D printing experience is primarily with ultrasonic additive manufacturing (embedding FBG sensors into aluminum/process-based research), and recently I was approached by someone interested in the potential value of using polypropylene (PP) for FDM.  My understanding is that it is fairly difficult to obtain meaningful results with it, but again this is out of my expertise.  I saw a few references to glass fiber reinforcement, something that is more up my alley, and have essentially the following questions:

1. Is there a decent market/interest in cheaper polypropylene filament/coming up with improved parameters for PP printing?
2. Is there an interest in cheap glass fiber reinforced-polypropylene (GFR-PP) filament?

If you have anything relevant to add on that I haven't considered, please feel free to chime in as well.

Comment: I would personally be SUPER interested in any new material that has increased mechanical properties. My primary concern with it would be though if the glass fibers would be all that useful in an FDM process since none of the fibers would bridge the layers. My guess would be that the layer strength would be improved but the layer bonding would be unaffected/